# importing mongoose just breaks execution

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

the line that causes the problem is jus importing mongoose into the code
`const mongoose = require("mongoose")`

and it drops the error:

```
C:\Users\libor\OneDrive\Escritorio\todo\dev\Aplay\proyectos\mustang-oneclic\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\add_user.js:16
        this.options = options ?? {};
                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\libor\OneDrive\Escritorio\todo\dev\Aplay\proyectos\mustang-oneclic\node_modules\mongodb\lib\admin.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

if I remove the `require(` line the error doesn't apear

there is nothing interacting with mongodb nor mongoose, I have no clue what is happening

I tried installing mongodb in my pc again and removing the mongoose inport, nothing else is interacting with mongoose
I expected it to import like normal

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: You need at least Node.js v14 to make it work
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it
It ended up being that the mongoose version was ahead of my node version, thus causing errors for using features my version doesn't have
mongoose:"^7.4.1"
node: v12.22.1

now I'm using:
mongoose:"^5.9.20"

Comment: Node v12 reached end-of-life status over a year ago.